# Volume integral of electric field (hemisphere solid)

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Let $S$ be a hemisphere of radius $R$, and let $\sigma$ be the constant charge density at each point $(x',y',z')$ in $S$. The electric field generated by the hemisphere is a vector function: 
$$\mathbf E(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_S\frac{\sigma}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf r}\,dV,$$

Where $\hat{\mathbf r}$ is the unit vector from a point $(x',y',z')\in S$ to $(x,y,z)$, and $r^2$ is the squared distance from $(x',y',z')\in S$ to $(x,y,z)$. Consider the transformation from spherical coordinates to rectangular coordinates. Then, if we want to calculate the electric field at the centre $O$ of the hemisphere, i.e. the centre of the biggest circle that it contains, we would want to let the origin of the coordinate system to be at $O$. Once we do that, the electric field calculated at $O$ is:

$$\mathbf E = \frac{\sigma}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^R-\frac{(\rho',\phi',\theta')}{\rho'}\sin\phi\,d\rho'd\phi'd\theta'.$$

This integral will produce a $\ln\rho'|_0^R$, how do I deal with $\ln 0$? Did I commit any mistake? I appreciate your help in pointing out what could be wrong.

PS: I know I can solve the problem partitioning the hemisphere into rings, but I want this solution, thanks!

Comment: The issue is the integral is improper. To evaluate it, remove an $\epsilon$-ball from $S$ and compute the resulting integral. Then take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @kobe still there is a term $\ln R$, which shouldn't be part of the answer: $(\sigma R /4\epsilon_0,0,$anything$)$

Comment: According to my calculations, $\ln R$ is not present. It is indeed $\frac{\sigma R}{4\epsilon_0}\vec{k}$.

Comment: If I understood well, generating this $\epsilon$-ball is changing the limits for $\rho'$: $\epsilon\le\rho'\le R$ right?

Comment: Yes. I'll post my calculations up soon.

Comment: I appreciate it since I could be committing a different mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral is improper, so to evaluate it, we remove a $\delta$-ball inside $S$, convert to spherical coordinates, then take the limit as $\delta\to 0$. The result is

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E} &= \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_\delta^R \frac{\sigma}{r^2} \hat{r} r^2\sin \phi \, dr\, d\phi\, d\theta\\
&= \frac{\sigma}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_\delta^R \hat{r}\sin \phi\, dr\, d\phi\, d\theta\\
&= \frac{\sigma}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_\delta^R \langle\cos \theta\sin\phi, \sin\theta\sin \phi, \sin \phi\rangle\sin \phi\, dr\, d\phi\, d\theta\\
&= \frac{\sigma}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} (R - \delta)\langle\cos\theta\sin^2\phi, \sin\theta\sin^2\phi, \sin^2\phi\rangle\, d\phi\, d\theta\\
&= \frac{\sigma R}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \lim_{\delta\to 0} (R - \delta) \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \langle \cos \theta\sin^2\phi, \sin\theta\sin^2\phi, \sin^2\phi\rangle\, d\phi\, d\theta \\
&= \frac{\sigma R}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \left\langle 0,0,2\pi \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\quad (\text{since $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin\theta \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\sin \theta\, d\theta = 0$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2\phi\, d\phi = 1/2$})\\
&= \frac{\sigma R}{4\epsilon_0}\vec{\mathbf{k}}.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I did not consider r hat that way

Comment: kobe, wouldn't the unit vector from a point $P$ in $S$ to the origin be $-\langle\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle$? where $\phi$ is the angle between the positive $z$ axis to the segment $\overline{OP}$ from the origin to the point and $\theta$ the angle between the positive $x$ axis and the projection of $\overline{OP}$ onto the $xy$ plane

Comment: The minus sign should not be present: $\hat{\mathbf{r}}(x,y,z)$ is the vector from the origin to $(x,y,z)$, i.e., $\langle x,y,z\rangle$. In spherical coordinates, this is $\langle \sin \phi\cos\theta, \sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\phi\rangle$.

Comment: @Vladmir please let me know more specifically what issue you have with my answer so I can address it.

Comment: @Vladmir putting the minus sign aside, the $z$-component you have should be $\cos \phi$, not $\cos \theta$. Think of it this way. If you were to take the norm of $-\langle \sin \phi\cos \theta, \sin \phi\sin \theta, \cos \theta\rangle$, you would get $\sqrt{\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\theta}$, which does not equal $1$.

Comment: The definition of $\hat{\bf r}$ in the electric field is a unit vector FROM a source charge, to the test charge. The source charges are the ones that belong to a fixed configuration on the space, and the test charge is one with very small charge so that it doesn't change the configuration of the source charges.

Therefore if we want to calculate the field at $O=(0,0,0)$, one should take $\hat{\bf r} = -\langle x,y,z\rangle/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ because that vector would be pointing from the points on the solid to the centre, always. In a similar fashion I'd like to get not the unit vector of...

Comment: ... spherical coordinates but one that points the other way (from the points on the solid to the centre)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was meant to be $\cos\phi$.

Comment: @Vladmir it's unconventional to have the position vector $\vec{\mathbf{r}}$ be pointing inward, but I'll simply put in the minus signs if it's defined inwardly. Besides that, my calculations are correct. I don't really the reason to unaccept.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of that vector $\hat{\bf r}$. I unaccepted the answer because I got scared thinking that it would be weird to have an electric field vector at $(0,0,0)$ pointing outwards the solid. Now I see that it can be possible.

Comment: So to be clear $\hat{\bf r}$ should be noted $\hat{\bf r}_{0j}$, which points from the $j$-th charge to the point at which we want to calculate the field

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done in a simple way,

```
    we all know that electric field created by disc of surface charge density 

      E=(rho)/2ϵ0 (1-cosθ)
```

so dividing the hemisphere into smaller discs of surface charge density (σ)(dz)
 and integrating the integral from zero to R.

```
 dE=  ((σ)(dz)/2ϵ0) (1-cosθ) 
 dE=  (σ/2ϵ0) (dz-zdz/R)      since Rcosθ=z

          ∫dE= (σ/2ϵ0) ( ∫dz-∫(zdz/R))   limitsfrom 0 to R

          E=  (σ/2ϵ0) ( R-R/2)

         E=  σR/4ϵ0
```

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) is a mathjax guide to type maths on this site.

Comment: We don't all know the result for a disk.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ${\bf r}$ vector is not $(\rho', \phi', \theta')$, rather it is ${\hat{\bf e}}_r$, hence there is no logarithm.

Comment: I took $\hat{\mathbf r} = - \dfrac{(\rho',\phi',\theta')}{\rho'}$.

Comment: Indeed, but this is still not right. Consider the vector $\hat{{\bf r}}$ in cartesian coordinates, this is $\hat{{\bf r}} = \frac{x \hat{\bf i} + y \hat{\bf j} +z \hat{\bf k}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$. In spherical coordinates the vector $\hat{\bf r}=\hat{\bf e}_{r}$ does not have the same expression, it is a basis vector. What you probably need for your calculation is to resolve $\hat{\bf e}_r$ in cartesian coordinates and see that only the $z$-component survives